# Populating a drop down based on a text field Javascript/Coldfusion 8

Tags: javascript, coldfusion-8

I have a page that has around 30 different entry fields, one of the top fields is a textfield and after this is filled in, I want to populate a dropdown and a textfield. I currently have it calling a javascript function, however my main problem is that I need to query the database to find out what value to populate the fields with.

Here is the type of thing I was trying to do:

```
function populateState(){

<cfquery name="getState" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    SELECT STATE_CODE, CODE_ID
    FROM LERG_LATA_V1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Code ON STATE_CODE = CHAR1_TX
    WHERE NPX = #NPANXX#
</cfquery>
}
```

And then after that I would need to read the result and select that element. Any suggestions on how to do this? Most of what I am finding on my google searches are saying you cannot mix cf and js since they execute at different times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either create a state JavaScript array with your query, and then reference that in your javascript, or use the built-in `cfselect` tag binding to make this happen. Here's a simple example of how I do this:

http://www.dansshorts.com/post/cfselect-binding-and-selectedvalues

Dan

Comment: That binding looks like it might be close to what I am looking for, but it looks like the only way I could get the item I want selected would be to have that as the first record, is there any way to use the binding like that to manipulate what is selected rather than manipulate the record?

Comment: Any manipulation has to happen on the client-side if you don't want to return your selection as the first entry. There's nothing built into CF currently to make that happen.